# How to judge whether the BigDecimal division operation is indivisible in Java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

When we do arithmetic, we often keep the whole decimal if we can divide it completely, and we have to keep a few decimal places if we can't divide it completely.At present, BigDecimal either chooses to directly divide and may have abnormalities, or keeps all decimals.

How to keep the decimals only when the decimals are endless? Lose as little information as possible

Expected effect:
1/4=0.25
1/3=0.3333

Comment: What result do you want it to give you, for example, when you divide 1 by 3? Please give more details about what you are asking, e.g. by giving examples of expected vs. actual behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can use [BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,int,java.math.RoundingMode)) and specify a large enough scale argument to keep a sufficient number of decimal places:

```
BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 10, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
-> 0.3333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, "keeping" the decimal is in terms of the value's representation.

So, if it's *0.3* repeating, then you would typically denote this using a line over the *3*, or sometimes an ellipsis, *"0.3 ..."*.

> *"... At present, BigDecimal either chooses to directly divide and may have abnormalities ..."*

This I am unaware of, it typically returns exact values for me; I've never seen it deviate.

The *[BigDecimal#divide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal))* method, it will throw an error if the result is *non-terminating*.

For example, this will produce an error.

```java
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ONE;
value = value.divide(new BigDecimal("3"));
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1769)
    at Example.main(Example.java:8)
```

Here is the excerpt from the JavaDoc, for *BigDecimal#divide*.

> *"**Throws:***
> *ArithmeticException - if the exact quotient does not have a terminating decimal expansion, including dividing by zero"*

What you could do is apply a *scale* and *[RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html)* to the division.
The *scale* here is the amount of digits after the decimal point.

I typically use the *[RoundingMode#HALF_UP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP)* mode.

```java
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ONE;
BigDecimal three = new BigDecimal("3");
value = value.divide(three, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Output

```
0.33333
```